# OptGroup not working in Android 2.3 but works fine in 4.1

Tags: jquery-mobile, select, cordova-2.0.0, optgroup

I have created an opt-group in my app its working fine in 4.1 Android but not in 2.3.Can any one tell me whats the problem and if its not supported than which is the best way to create something like that.
any idea is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is not working in your optgroup? some code, screenshots of the error might help :)

Comment: hey sorry but it was my mistake I didn't added data to the table so it was not working.